# Display string with two apostrophes triggers error

Tags: php, string

Does anyone know why I can't do this:

```
echo "Re: 'APPEL D'OFFRES";
```

It redirects me to a forbidden error page.

But if I do this:

```
echo "Re: APPEL D'OFFRES";
```

It works.

The string is ASCII. What should I look after?

EDIT:

I am sure it's something with the php.ini settings. It's not the first time I writee this, but never happened to get such error. I also add that this code is not the only on the page. I have to modify a phpBB file, and need this at a point. I do the "echo" and place an exit after it. I get the error, it doesn't go up to the "exit;".

EDIT2:

This one works too echo "Re: \'APPEL D\'OFFRES";

Comment: Have you tried echo "Re: \'APPEL D\'OFFRES";?
Anyway your code looks valid to me..

Comment: Look in the error logs. What's the error message?

Comment: Your code works fine (http://codepad.viper-7.com/kPWyXn). It's something in the hosting or in php's settings.

Comment: Is that really the only code on that page?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
echo 'Re: \'APPEL D\'OFFRES';
```